# Error SSIS in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a package in SSIS working correctly.
This package executes and does the steps that I programmed to do, but I have a problem, I believe someone else has already gone through this.
Following:
I've Deployed SSIS, created Job in SQL Server, but at the time I'm going to run Job, it can not connect to a Server that is Read Only.
Already check the connections, they are working properly.
Here is the error:

> Load Information in the Table Returns_Actions: Error: SIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER. Call of the
>   AcquireConnection method for connection manager '' Multicobra01 ''
>   with error code 0xC0202009. Error messages may have been posted
>   earlier with more information about why the call failed for the
>   AcquireConnection method.

Anyway, that's the problem I'm facing.

In SSIS I use TASK: `OLE DB SOURCE`, I've already switched to ADO NET Source, and it did not solve my problem.

can you help me?

Comment: Post ALL of the error messages.   The one you have posted doesn't give enough information to help.

Comment: If it works locally but not when you deploy it, it could be a permissions issue that the server account that runs the SQL jobs does not have the proper access to the DBs in your job.  Or it could be a firewall/port issue where the server where your job is does not have access/can not reach the server that your database is on.

Comment: The error is this: Load information in the Returns_Actions table: Error: SIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER. Call of the AcquireConnection method for connection manager '' Multicobra01 '' with error code 0xC0202009. Error messages may have been posted earlier with more information about why the call failed in the AcquireConnection method.

Comment: As already mentioned, find the "Error messages may have been posted earlier" that provide useful error message info. There's nothing in the message you posted that gives any clue.